# Create a DocX and save to client machine c#

Tags: c#, docx

I am using the library from:
https://github.com/xceedsoftware/DocX/blob/master/Xceed.Document.NET/Src/Document.cs
in an MVC Project.

The functionality is now sitting on my server;

```
 public void Build(Results umbracoFormValues)
    {
        var ms = new MemoryStream();
        using (var document = DocX.Create(ms))
        {
            var heading = new Heading();
            heading.Branding(document);
            var sections = umbracoFormValues.SectionResults;
            foreach (var section in sections)
            {
                heading.Render(document, section);
                ConstructFieldTypes(document, section);
                new Footer().Render(document);
            }
            ms.Position = 0;
            document.SaveAs(new CreateNew().DocumentFileName(umbracoFormValues));
        }
    }
```

How do I then grab the newly created file and make it downloadable to the user/client?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: There are a *lot* of duplicate questions asking how to download files. You didn't mention which stack is used though. In the latest versions it could be as simple as `return File(ms)` or `return File(docPath)` in a controller action

Comment: Yeah I did have an extensive look at all the duplicate answers, but can't seem to get it to work. I am using .net framework 4.72.

Hence me asking again a duplicate question.

Comment: What can't you get to work? You *have* to use `File()` or return a FileResult. All of the duplicates work because there's no other way. The code you posted makes no attempt to return a file though. It doesn't even show a controller action

Comment: It's probably as I am using; https://our.umbraco.com/documentation/Add-ons/umbracoforms/developer/extending/adding-a-workflowtype

Answer (score 2):

You can change your Build method to return the stream:

```
public Stream Build(Results umbracoFormValues)
{
    var ms = new MemoryStream();
    //code omitted for simplicity
    return ms;
}
```

Then in your action:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> MyAction(Results umbracoFormValues)
{
    var stream = Build(umbracoFormValues);

    var mimeType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessing";
    var fileName = "myReport.docx";

    return File(stream, mimeType, fileName);
}
```

Keep in mind that there may be some differences depending on the dotnet core/framework you're using, as you haven't specified that.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me, I apologise for not including the framework that I am using. 

I am using .net framework 4.72

Comment: @user3419151 which means `File()` is available. It's available in both MVC and Web API, in all versions